# If I use a 5A power pack for 3 led strips 2A will the power pack burn

Tags: power-supply, power

I'm trying to make a light and I'm using 2A 12v aluminium led strip lights.

But I need to know how to select the power supply for this.

I'm using 8 led strips:

4 strips 2.5 feet

4 strips 1.5 feet

6 pc cooling fan

I have a 12v 5A power pack can I use it for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the LED strips the kind with multiple groups of 3 LEDs and a resistor?
If yes, each group of 3 will draw ~25-30mA.
Count up the # of groups, do the math, see if the total is under 5A. If it is, you're good to do.

If the LEDs are something else, post a picture of them.